# Fragment - Cannot cast from Context in 'CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener'

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-edittext

I'm using auto complete text listener in sqlite at my Fragment java class, unfortunately I'm having an error nullpointerexception. Here is my logcat:

```
05-12 09:15:05.987: E/AndroidRuntime(20901): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 09:15:05.987: E/AndroidRuntime(20901): Process: iot.bayadcenter.slidingmenu, PID: 20901
05-12 09:15:05.987: E/AndroidRuntime(20901): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-12 09:15:05.987: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at iot.bayadcenter.slidingmenu.billers.Payment.getItemsFromDb(Payment.java:271)
05-12 09:15:05.987: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at iot.bayadcenter.searchbarsqlite.CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener.onTextChanged(CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener.java:42)
05-12 09:15:05.987: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7610)
05-12 09:15:05.987: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7672)
```

And here is my CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener.java

```
public class CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener implements TextWatcher{

public static final String TAG = "CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener.java";
Context context;

public CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence userInput, int start, int before, int count) {

    // if you want to see in the logcat what the user types
    Log.e(TAG, "User input: " + userInput);

    Payment mainActivity = new Payment();

    // query the database based on the user input
    mainActivity.item = mainActivity.getItemsFromDb(userInput.toString());//HERE IS LINE 42

    // update the adapater
    mainActivity.myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mainActivity.myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mainActivity.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, mainActivity.item);
    mainActivity.myAutoComplete.setAdapter(mainActivity.myAdapter);

}
```

}

and here is my Fragment(Payment.java)

```
public class Payment extends Fragment {

CustomAutoCompleteView myAutoComplete;

    // adapter for auto-complete
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;

    // for database operations
    DatabaseHandler databaseH;

    // just to add some initial value
    String[] item = new String[] {"Please search..."};

    Context ctx = getActivity();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            myAutoComplete = (CustomAutoCompleteView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myautocomplete);

            // add the listener so it will tries to suggest while the user types
            myAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener(getActivity()));

            // set our adapter
            myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, item);
            myAutoComplete.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

And here is the other part:

```
// this function is used in CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener.java
    public String[] getItemsFromDb(String searchTerm){

        // add items on the array dynamically
        List<MyObject> products = databaseH.read(searchTerm);//HERE IS MY LINE 27
        int rowCount = products.size();

        String[] item = new String[rowCount];
        int x = 0;

        for (MyObject record : products) {

            item[x] = record.objectName;
            x++;
        }

        return item;
    }
```

Comment: what error do you have? post logcat please.

Comment: I'm not able to execute it yet because of the said error.

Comment: is `CustomAutoCompleteView` is extended from `AutoCompleteTextView`? In that class did you set that it must accept as listener not `TextWatcher`, but custom listener? I guess that is because of it.

Comment: However, I was able to remove the error on the code and execute it just now. But I'm still having an error, please see logcat above.

Comment: `Payment.java:271` is the problem line, could you show full code of this class?

Comment: Please check the codes I have updated. But I thought that the cause of  error is because of this line 'Payment mainActivity = new Payment();' in CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener.java..since line 42 is also the cause of error.

Answer (score 0):

Since here is full bunch of exceptions, let's start from the first one which is visible. Line #271 produces a `NullPointerException`, this is

```
List<MyObject> products = databaseH.read(searchTerm);
```

I guess this is because `databaseH` is null. Check if you open connection properly.
Also this line made me wondered `Payment mainActivity = new Payment();`. Create new instance of `Fragment` in custom class which implements `TextWatcher`... Don't call any of methods from `Fragment` unless it is not on the screen. Also `Fragment`s are used to be attached to `Activity`, but not as for handling database methods. Take a look at pattern [MVC](http://konmik.github.io/introduction-to-model-view-presenter-on-android.html).
I think here is not much sense to fix bugs, would be better to reorganize everything.
Hope it helps at least a little.